# Classes and types in python

Tags: python-3.x

I started learning python recently. I came across this statement
Classes and types are themselves objects, and they are of type *type*. So what does this statement actually means?

Comment: Exactly what it says: `type(int) == type`... Everything in Python is a class' object, including classes. The class of a class is the class `type`

Answer (score 0):

You can store variables and functions in classes.
What makes it different from global variable and function is that you may assign more than 1 object to the same class.
For example:

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def find_type(self):
        return type(self.x)
obj1 = my_class(1)
obj2 = my_class('apple')
print(obj1.find_type())
print(obj2.find_type())
print(obj1.x)
print(obj2.x)
```

You get:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
1
apple
```

A class my contain multiple functions and variables so you cannot just find the type of something in it by doing `type(my_class)` which will always return the `<class 'type'>`